# Is there a way to set bind_address from command line in mysql 5.5 without restarting?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, command-line

I made a modification to `bind_address` in `my.cnf` that knocked down a monitor. It has been repaired since, firewall allowing the monitor IP in. However, mysql is still running in its previous state since restart.

In MySQL 5.5, there does not seem to be a `bind_address` variable available from CLI (unless I'm missing something). Is there a way I can set `bind_address` from CLI so I don't have to restart mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no. Why?

[MySQL Documentation on bind_address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) says right in the beginning

```
Command-Line Format --bind-address=addr
System Variable (>= 5.6.1)  Name    bind_address
Variable Scope  Global
Dynamic Variable    No
Permitted Values (<= 5.6.5) Type    string
Default 0.0.0.0
Permitted Values (>= 5.6.6) Type    string
Default *
```

It's a global variable in MySQL 5.6, but it is not dynamic.

Since you are using MySQL 5.5, [it is only a startup option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address).

Therefore, you must [bite the bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bite_the_bullet) and restart mysqld.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the doc too, but I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some workaround/hack out there that would allow the impossible :)